# Zero knowledge token for communicating files one has

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there a method for individuals to publish a token which indicates having a file in their local set of files without revealing exactly what they have?

For these purposes we will consider a file to be a string of ones and zeros. Padding a 1 to the left maps each file an integer.

Suppose I have three files on my computer, a b and c.

A: 0x00FFA
B: 0x1
C: 0x666A

A web server wants to know if I already have file B.

Of course it could transmit a 256bit hash of B, and ask if I have it, and my computer would do a lookup and report back. But I wanted to know if there is a way to pre-publish a fixed length token which represents every file I have, so the server need not ask- instead it checks the hash of file B against the token.

My instinct is that this should not be practically possible in a fixed ( eg 256 bit) token because adding files to the set might dilute the information resource and the token will have false positives crop up quickly, but I am not sure. Perhaps there is a precise method to choose a token length for a given number of files and collision probability threshold?

Comment: Imagine you could reveal a token $T$ that lets the server check non-interactively whether file $f$ is in your local repository. In this case the server could simply try a bunch of different $f_i$ locally to see whether you have any of them. What exactly is the security notion (against a malicious server) that you would like to satisfy? Concretely, which privacy guarantees are you hoping for?

Comment: The idea is that the token would allow you to check against the sha256 hash of a file. So the server would not know what files you had unless it knew the file that generated the sha.

Comment: It sounds a little bit like bloom filters are the data structure you are looking for, but it is still unclear what security you want. In general you cannot assume that you learn nothing about a file if you are just given its hash. A hash is not an encryption and may leak small, but important parts of the file in plain.